# Unable to delete any email using JavaMail API in Android

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I have been trying to delete emails using JavaMail API in android. I am already able to fetch and see the emails in my application. Though not able to delete any email, there is no error or any warning that could lead to the resolution. Here is what I am trying so far. Help is highly appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.emazdoor.encmail.customlistview.MainList;
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder;

public class DeleteEmail {

    static Message[] messages;

    public static void delete(final int number)

    {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                try {

                    int num = number;
                    Store store = null;
                    Properties props = System.getProperties();
                    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

                    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

                    store = session.getStore("imaps");
                    store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", dumber.username,
                            dumber.password);

                    // create the folder object and open it
                    IMAPFolder emailFolder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
                    emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

                    // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and
                    // print it
                    messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
                    System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        Message message = messages[i];

                    }
                    if (messages != null && messages.length > 0)
                        messages[817].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);

                    // expunges the folder to remove messages which are marked
                    // deleted
                    emailFolder.close(true);
                    store.close();

                } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
I would be using variable in `messages[variable].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);` instead of hard coded value.

**UPDATE**
I set `setDebug(true)` and this is what I got...Seems everything is okay..

```
07-06 23:06:34.886: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
07-06 23:06:34.886: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
07-06 23:06:34.886: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
07-06 23:06:36.896: I/System.out(10749): * OK Gimap ready for requests from 103.255.6.118 q11mb517503595ywb
07-06 23:06:36.896: I/System.out(10749): A0 CAPABILITY
07-06 23:06:37.251: I/System.out(10749): * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=XOAUTH
07-06 23:06:37.251: I/System.out(10749): A0 OK Thats all she wrote! q11mb517503595ywb
07-06 23:06:37.256: I/System.out(10749): IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH2
07-06 23:06:37.256: I/System.out(10749): IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
07-06 23:06:37.256: I/System.out(10749): IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
07-06 23:06:37.261: I/System.out(10749): IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH
07-06 23:06:37.261: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap.googlemail.com, user=emazdoor@gmail.com , password=<non-null>
07-06 23:06:37.266: I/System.out(10749): A1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
07-06 23:06:37.571: I/System.out(10749): + 
07-06 23:06:37.601: I/System.out(10749): ZW1hemRvb3JAZ21haWwuY29tIABlbWF6ZG9vckBnbWFpbC5jb20gAGltYXNkdXJyYW5p
07-06 23:06:38.236: I/System.out(10749): * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT
07-06 23:06:38.256: I/System.out(10749): A1 OK emazdoor@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
07-06 23:06:38.281: I/System.out(10749): A2 CAPABILITY
07-06 23:06:38.696: I/System.out(10749): * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT
07-06 23:06:38.701: I/System.out(10749): A2 OK Success
07-06 23:06:38.716: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
07-06 23:06:38.721: I/System.out(10749): A3 SELECT INBOX
07-06 23:06:39.191: I/System.out(10749): * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
07-06 23:06:39.191: I/System.out(10749): * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing \*)] Flags permitted.
07-06 23:06:39.196: I/System.out(10749): * OK [UIDVALIDITY 651814458] UIDs valid.
07-06 23:06:39.196: I/System.out(10749): * 814 EXISTS
07-06 23:06:39.196: I/System.out(10749): * 0 RECENT
07-06 23:06:39.196: I/System.out(10749): * OK [UIDNEXT 1771] Predicted next UID.
07-06 23:06:39.201: I/System.out(10749): * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 101785]
07-06 23:06:39.201: I/System.out(10749): A3 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)
07-06 23:06:39.316: I/System.out(10749): messages.length---814
07-06 23:06:39.316: I/System.out(10749): A4 STORE 3 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
07-06 23:06:40.121: I/System.out(10749): * 3 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
07-06 23:06:40.126: I/System.out(10749): A4 OK Success
07-06 23:06:40.156: I/System.out(10749): A5 EXPUNGE
07-06 23:06:40.601: I/System.out(10749): * 3 EXPUNGE
07-06 23:06:40.636: I/System.out(10749): * 813 EXISTS
07-06 23:06:40.641: I/System.out(10749): A5 OK Success
07-06 23:06:40.671: I/System.out(10749): A6 CLOSE
07-06 23:06:41.081: I/System.out(10749): A6 OK Returned to authenticated state. (Success)
07-06 23:06:41.116: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
07-06 23:06:41.121: I/System.out(10749): A7 LOGOUT
07-06 23:06:41.531: I/System.out(10749): * BYE LOGOUT Requested
07-06 23:06:41.551: I/System.out(10749): A7 OK 73 good day (Success)
07-06 23:06:41.561: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: IMAPStore connection dead
07-06 23:06:41.561: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
07-06 23:06:41.566: I/System.out(10749): DEBUG: IMAPStore cleanup done
```

Comment: I had this weird issue, add `emailFolder.expunge();` before `emailFolder.close(true);`

Comment: @ProtectLifeSaveForests no that didnt help either :(

Comment: What does the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: First, change your Gmail password immediately.  You're using a very old version of JavaMail, and because of that you've just exposed your (encoded) Gmail password.  Upgrade to a [newer version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: The debug output doesn't show any problems.  What makes you believe your message is not deleted?  How are you looking for the message to see if it was deleted?  Note that [Gmail doesn't exactly follow the IMAP spec](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Gmail); when you expunge a message Gmail just moves it to the Trash folder, if you expunge it from there then it really goes away.